# JavaScript - variables inside nested forEach loop through undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of `this.userId` while inside the second for loop, it throughs `undefined`.
Have a look at the code below:

```
 //the following variable gets undefined inside the second for loop
  this.userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');

  this.reviews.forEach(function(element1){

    element1.usersWhoLike.forEach(function(element2) {

   if(element2 == this.userId){
       //this throughs undefined !!
       console.log('UserID is : ',this.userId)
   }

  });

  });
```

Comment: `userId` is not the same as `this.userId`.

Comment: @RaymondChen corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed scope of function inside forEach
Let's try:

```
this.reviews.forEach(function(element1){

    element1.usersWhoLike.forEach(function(element2) {

   if(element2 == userId){
       //this throughs undefined !!
       console.log('UserID is : ',this.userId)
   }

  }, this);

  }, this);
```

Comment: It worked! But how ?

Comment: @HamzaL. The 2nd argument given to `.forEach()` controls the value of `this` inside the iterator `function`s. Passing `this` as that argument ensures that all 3 functions (2 iterators and the function surrounding the snippet) use the same value.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Got it, thank you!

Comment: For more detail. You can see the list parameters here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example#Parameters

Answer (score 0):

this.userId in the second one is referring to the function scope itself. Try adding a var self as a reference

```
    this.userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');

    var self = this; // Referencing
    this.reviews.forEach(function(element1){

        element1.usersWhoLike.forEach(function(element2) {

            if(element2 == userId){
                //this throughs undefined !!
                console.log('UserID is : ',self.userId)
            }

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
```

Put this line inside first loop